# Overlay listview at bottom of viewpager and focus on current item

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

Hello Everyone I am Developing one Gallery app.
I have implemented Gridview and displayed images from server.when click on that image it will open one dialog and dialog contain viewpager and listview at bottom.

According to the viewpager position image it will smooth slide listview also.

Problem:I want to display overlay layer on listview and display only current item focused and other item are looks like blurish.

Here is my code

```
 imagelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
            imagdialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            imagdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            imagdialog.setContentView(R.layout.imagelist);
            imagdialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface arg0) {
                    // recreate();
                    selectedAdapter = new Sadapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
                    imagelist.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
                }
            });


            photoid = arraylist.get(i).getId();
            Log.v("Photoid111", "" + photoid);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(imagdialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            imagdialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            viewpager = (ViewPager) imagdialog.findViewById(R.id.img);
            final Button accept = (Button) imagdialog.findViewById(R.id.accept);
            final Button reject = (Button) imagdialog.findViewById(R.id.reject);
            final EditText cmnts = (EditText) imagdialog.findViewById(R.id.comnt);
            ImageView closewin = (ImageView) imagdialog.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
            imglist = (RecyclerView) imagdialog.findViewById(R.id.imglist);
            LinearLayoutManager sublimationmanager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(imagdialog.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            imglist.setLayoutManager(sublimationmanager);
            cmnts.setText("" + arraylist.get(i).getCmnts());
            cmnts.setSelection(cmnts.getText().length());


            adaptor = new ViewPager_Adaptor(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            viewpager.setAdapter(adaptor);
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(i);
            img_adaptor = new Image_list(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
            imglist.setAdapter(img_adaptor);
            imglist.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
            pos = i;

            viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    photoid = arraylist.get(position).getId();
                    Log.v("Photoid", "" + photoid);
                    cmnts.setText("" + arraylist.get(position).getCmnts());
                    cmnts.setSelection(cmnts.getText().length());
                    imglist.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
                    pos = position;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
            });

            closewin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    imagdialog.dismiss();
                    selectedAdapter = new Sadapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
                    imagelist.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
                }
            });
            accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    comments = cmnts.getText().toString();
                    Log.v("Photoid", "" + photoid);
                    Log.v("Photoid", "" + comments);

                    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                    if (isInternetPresent) {
                        mdialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                        mdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                        mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
                        mdialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                        mdialog.setCancelable(false);

                        mdialog.show();
                        new Accept().execute(URL.amateurpath + "Accept");

                    } else {
                        if (imagdialog.isShowing())
                            imagdialog.dismiss();
                        nonetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        main_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        noimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });

            reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    comments = cmnts.getText().toString();
                    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                    if (isInternetPresent) {
                        mdialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                        mdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                        mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
                        mdialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                        mdialog.setCancelable(false);

                        mdialog.show();
                        new Reject().execute(URL.amateurpath + "Reject");
                    } else {
                        if (imagdialog.isShowing())
                            imagdialog.dismiss();
                        nonetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        main_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        noimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });
            imagdialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Here is my Viewpager Adaptor

```
public class ViewPager_Adaptor extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<CustomImages> data;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ViewPager_Adaptor(Context context, ArrayList<CustomImages> arraylist) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        Log.d("Abhi", data.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("DATASIZE", String.valueOf(data.size()));

        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_img, container, false);
        final ImageView iimg = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        ImageView clockw = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.clock);

        ImageView anticlockw = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.anticlock);

        clockw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iimg.setRotation(iimg.getRotation() + 90);

            }
        });
        anticlockw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iimg.setRotation(iimg.getRotation() - 90);

            }
        });
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(data.get(position).getUrl().replaceAll(" ", "%20")).placeholder(R.drawable.temp_img).error(R.drawable.no_media).into(iimg);
        iimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intnt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageShow.class);
                intnt.putExtra("photo", data.get(position).getPhoto());
                intnt.putExtra("url", data.get(position).getUrl());
                startActivity(intnt);
            }
        });


        container.addView(itemview);
        return itemview;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

And finally Listview adapter is as follows

```
    public class Image_list extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Image_list.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<CustomImages> arraylist1;
    Context c;

    public Image_list(Context c, ArrayList<CustomImages> arraylist) {
        this.arraylist1 = arraylist;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.inflate_image_list, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.v("Position of i", "" + pos);
 //            if (pos == position) {
 //                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
 //            } else {
 //
```

//            }

```
        Picasso
                .with(this.c)
                .load(arraylist1.get(position).getUrl().replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.temp_img) // can also be a drawable
                .placeholder(R.drawable.temp_img)
                .error(R.drawable.no_media)
                .into(holder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arraylist1.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.catimg);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getLayoutPosition();

                    viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:I want to display overlay layer on listview and display only current item focused and other item are looks like blurish.

As concern to the problem i managed to slide list according to the viewpager slide but i want to display blurissh image and focus only one image from listview which is displayed in viewpager.

And display image from list at right of screen which is displayed in viewpager

Answer (score 1):

Whenever one item is selected in the viewPager get the position of that item. Save the position of that item in a variable `viewPagerPosition` in the adapter. Then refresh the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In the adapter have a view with certain transparency and make that visible as default.In adapter's onBindViewHolder check

```
if(position = viewPagerPosition){
    transparentView.setVisibility(GONE);
} else{
    transparentView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

This should make the current view highlighted and other dimmed. If you want blur then you can use blur with the same condition.

Comment: Where should i write the notifydatasetchanged

Comment: call notifydatasetchanged from onItemSelected in viewpager's onPageChangeListener

Comment: Sorry sir i will check today and inform you if solved Thanks a lot sir

Comment: You're supposed to accept the answer if it solves your problem.